# CLI version in CodeBuild is not compatible with the library version

Tags: command-line-interface, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a CDK application with CDK pipeline to deploy it. Recently I needed to bump "aws-cdk-lib"  dependency in my application to "^2.40.0". Now when CDK pipeline runs with this update - it throws this error at "cdk synth" stage:

```
This CDK CLI is not compatible with the CDK library used by your application. Please upgrade the CLI to the latest version.
(Cloud assembly schema version mismatch: Maximum schema version supported is 17.0.0, but found 21.0.0)
```

From what I read, it supposed to always use the latest CLI, but even if I specifically set `cliVersion: '2.40.0'` property of the pipeline - it still throws the same error.

Any idea how to install the correct version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was using `npx cdk synth` command which always used an older version of CDK. Using `npx aws-cdk synth` uses the latest and no longer throws error.

**Update**: explainer.

Basically when I was running `npx cdk` - it was running CDK installed via `package.json`, which had older version specified, while running `npx aws-cdk` runs it directly from npm repo - and always the latest version.

So an alternative solution can be bumping cdk dependency in the `package.json` to the latest version - then `npx cdk` would work as well.

Comment: Where did you learn this? Could you update the answer with a link please?

Comment: @Luke I added the explainer.